# cannot pass drawable into android.R.drawable

Tags: android

Just trying to pass my alarm.png file into android.R.drawable. But I am receiving a "Cannot resolve symbol 'alarm'" when I try. I have my alarm.png in my layout folder so I dont know why it cant be recognized. I looked up this problem and seen a common problem is not having the correct package name and I don't believe there is anything wrong with that.

```
package com.example.em********er.chorelist;

public class Adapter {
    private static final String[] titles = {"hello", "wow", "bean"};
    private static final int[] icons = {android.R.drawable.alarm};
}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to get `alarm.png` from Android's drawable resource `R`. You need `your-package.R.drawable.alarm` instead of `android.R.drawable.alarm`

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a difference between this answer and Mohammed's answer because they both work.

Comment: @RyderThacker The only difference is that when you use `R.drawable` you'll find `R` under your imports where it's the same as `<your-package.R>`. In my answer, we mention it inline. Both ways are good, but if you're gonna use `R` at multiple places in the same file, import it and then use `R.` instead of using `<your-packahe>.R.` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **android.R.drawable.alarm** use **R.drawable.alarm** it will point to your drawable files instead of android's inbuilt drawables.